# Allow Git in firewall

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, git, firewall

I'm on Windows 8.1 and I configured my firewall to, by default, block all connections from all applications, both inbound and outbound. Only few programs are allowed, such as Chrome, Firefox, Pip, etc.

I also want to allow Git to connect to internet, but the problem is because I have no idea which exe file actually connects to the internet. There are literally hundreds of exe files in `C:\Program Files\Git` and subfolders.

There are four `git.exe` files (in different folders), I allowed all of them, but Git still cannot connect to Github. I also allowed few more files I though was used to connect to the internet, but it still cannot establish the connection. Also, I tried to use ProcessMonitor to track which process actually tries to connect to internet, but without luck. It seems that when I call `git.exe`, several processes are spawned and probably few of them requires internet connection.

Of course, when I turn off my firewall, it works properly, but I don't want to do it. I'm looking for a way to just allow as few exe files as possible in order to make Git works. Where I can find which of Git exe files actually need connection?

Sorry for my horrible english and thank you in advance :)

#### Edit

I don't want to block whole port, I want to block just as few exe files as possible from Git directory. Thanks.